# Why doesn't the following html and css hover code work when I add additional hyperlink within a div?

Tags: html, css, frontend

The following code works(lets say case 1)

```
<div>
        <a href="#" id="TAMIL">TAMIL</a>

        <span id="subheader1">
           <a href="#" >NEWS</a>
           <a href="#" >AUDIO</a>
        </span>
     </div>   


<style="text/css>"
#subheader1{    
    display: none;
}
#TAMIL{
    display: block;    
}
#TAMIL:hover + #subheader1{
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

but not this (say case 2)

```
<div>
        <a href="#" id="TAMIL">TAMIL</a>
        <a href="#" id="TELUGU">TELUGU</a>
        <span id="subheader1">
           <a href="#" >NEWS</a>
           <a href="#" >AUDIO</a>
        </span>
     </div>   

     <style="text/css>"
#subheader1{    
    display: none;
}
#TAMIL{
    display: block;    
}
#TAMIL:hover + #subheader1{
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

Why? Please help me.
Why is that its not working when I just add another hyperlink?
Here is the  http://jsfiddle.net/cor6bay6/1/

Comment: Machaa, you need `#TAMIL:hover ~ #subheader1`. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` adjacent sibling selector requires that the adjacent sibling be the *very next* items following.

In your case you need the general sibling selector.

```
#TAMIL:hover ~ #subheader1{
    display:block;
}
```

[**The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: I answered first! Yay! `:)`

Comment: 5 seconds...I can deal with it.

Comment: LoL. We are always competing with each other! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

This `+` selects the adjacent one. You are looking for general sibling selector. Use the following and it works:

```css
#TAMIL:hover ~ #subheader1
```

So finally you need to give:

```css
#TAMIL:hover ~ #subheader1 {
    display:block;
}
```